# type object 'Book' has no attribute 'order_by'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model for book:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    publish_house = models.ForeignKey(PublishHouse, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    objects = models.Manager()

    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='books/', default='books/no.png')
    img_inside = models.ImageField(upload_to='books/', 
                              default='books/no_inside.png')
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    book_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    is_best_selling = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Book'
```

I want to display books in templates by date (showing books that added recently), and this is the view:

```
def index(request):
    new_books = Book.order_by('-book_date')[:4]
    bestselling_books = Book.objects.filter('is_best_selling')[:4]
    book_context = {
        'new_books': new_books,
        'bestselling_books': bestselling_books,
    }
    advertises = Advertise.objects.all()
    adv_context = {
        'advertises': advertises
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', adv_context, book_context)
```

i want to display books in order by the date they were added

it keeps giving that error:

```
type object 'Book' has no attribute 'order_by'
```

Answer (score 1):

Book doesn't have an attribute `order_by`, its manager does

So you need

```
Book.objects.order_by
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line

```
new_books = Book.objects.order_by('-book_date')[:4]
```

to

```
new_books = Book.objects.order_by('-book_date')[:4]
```

because `order_by` is available in model manager.

**Update:**

```
def index(request):
    new_books = Book.order_by('-book_date')[:4]
    bestselling_books = Book.objects.filter(is_best_selling=True)[:4]
    advertises = Advertise.objects.all()
    book_context = {
        'new_books': new_books,
        'bestselling_books': bestselling_books,
        'advertises': advertises
    }

    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', book_context)
```

Comment: in tutorials he didn't added .objects, but i tried to add it and it gave me that error:
too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: still the same also

Comment: It's may be occurred for this line `return render(request, 'pages/index.html', adv_context, book_context)`

Comment: I've deleted `bestselling_books = Book.objects.filter('is_best_selling')[:4]` and also     `'bestselling_books': bestselling_books` and that stopped the error, but in the template it doesn't display any books and show what I've written to appear in else statement in case no books are found

Comment: try with my updated answer and make sure to change in template

Comment: it worked but i had to delete `bestselling_books = Book.objects.filter('is_best_selling')[:4]` because it gave me again that unpack error and when i check the trace back, i found its line is highlighted

Comment: What do you want to filter by which parameter? I added a sample implementation in my answer.

Comment: i wanted to filter books who is in best selling section so yes it's like how you implemented in. but it takes me back to the original problem `type object 'Book' has no attribute 'order_by'` and adding `.objects` or removing it doesn't make any difference

Comment: make sure you have some entry in Book

Comment: you mean having some data in database?

Comment: is there anyway to reference to books whose is_best_selling Boolean value is true, just in the template? like books.is_best_selling = True (i don't know the right way to do it just assuming)

Comment: i replaced `bestselling_books = Book.objects.filter('is_best_selling')[:4]` with `    bestselling_books = Book.objects.all().filter(is_best_selling=True)[:4]
`then it worked but it doesn't show me any books in template

Comment: `is_best_selling = models.BooleanField()` i added `default=False` as a parameter to it and it solved it